# how to add open weather map's weather map 1.0 using python?

Tags: python-3.x

how to add open weather map's weather map 1.0 using python?
https://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps

Comment: do you want to open the site?

Comment: Be a bit more precise. What do you want to achieve? Do you have any code of your own?

Comment: I want to preview weather maps 1.0 using python?

Answer (score 1):

```
import configparser
import requests
import sys

def get_api_key():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    return config['openweathermap']['api']

def get_weather(api_key, location):
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid= 
{}".format(location, api_key)

r = requests.get(url)
return r.json()

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        exit("Usage: {} LOCATION".format(sys.argv[0]))
    location = sys.argv[1]

    api_key = get_api_key()
    weather = get_weather(api_key, location)

    print(weather['main']['temp'])
    print(weather)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need weather. I need to get the weather maps 1.0.