# How do i convert Open weather map json format to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to convert a Open Weather Map Json format to pandas dataframe. I read some questions about this issue in stackoverflow like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971940/how-to-add-open-weather-maps-weather-map-1-0-using-python) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095379/converting-json-to-pandas-dataframe-with-weather-datasets)  but no one answer my question.
My Json format is like the below example:

```
{'coord': {'lon': 36.5707, 'lat': -113.7909}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04n'}], 'base': 'stations', 'main': {'temp': 272.49, 'feels_like': 272.49, 'temp_min': 272.49, 'temp_max': 272.49, 'pressure': 1025, 'humidity': 89, 'sea_level': 1025, 'grnd_level': 817}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': {'speed': 0.94, 'deg': 305, 'gust': 1.68}, 'clouds': {'all': 55}, 'dt': 1644685756, 'sys': {'country': 'US', 'sunrise': 1644636899, 'sunset': 1644675906}, 'timezone': 12600, 'id': 14256, 'name': 'xxx', 'cod': 200}
```

I know that i should use **json_normalize** function of pandas.
But i don't know how to use it.

I try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=36.7&lon=-113.5707&APPID="  


  response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
dicts = json.loads(data)
jsont = json.dumps(dicts)
df = pd.read_json(jsont, lines=True)
js =[]
js.append(json.loads(jsont))
print(js)
x =pd.json_normalize(js)
x.to_csv('E:/testjson.csv')
```

But i does not work.
I want to convert all keys of json to columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to transform JSON data into a flat table.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'coord': {'lon': 36.5707, 'lat': -113.7909}}
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(data)
>>> df.columns
Index(['coord.lon', 'coord.lat'], dtype='object')
```